# iText - formatting the substring

Tags: java, itext

Can I format the substring of some string (for example string for Paragraph - new Paragraph(someString) ) using any markers in Itext? Is something like that enabled?

For example:
new Paragraph("Congrats, you've [formatMarker]gained[/formatMarker] the privilege") ?

Comment: Probably. What have you tried/found?

Comment: Currently nothing. I have tried found any clue using google, but nothing. It's my first day with iText

Answer (score 1):

You can have iText parse HTML tags in order to format your text. Here is an example

```
Reader reader = new StringReader("<b>Here is Some HTML<b><h1>Hello World</h1>");
HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
worker.parse(reader);
```

When you parse it adds your contents to the document. No need to store them in a Paragraph. If you want more functionality and control over the individual elements of the html, you can try using the static method HTMLWorker.parseList()

The API for iText is here http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/ and it has lots of details on both methods used above